# How do I access an ImageView within an NSTableCellView in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I'm trying to programmatically populate the cells of a column with images already defined in an array (flags).

In IB I have an Image View directly within a Table Cell View. In the ViewController this is what I'm doing:

```
   public func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
      
      guard let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView else { return nil }
      
      if tableColumn?.title == "flag" {
         cellView.imageView?.image = NSImage(named: flags[row])   // NOT WORKING
      } else if tableColumn?.title == "country" {
         cellView.textField?.stringValue = flags[row].uppercased()
      }
      
      return cellView
   }
```

This results in the text field cells in the "country" column getting set fine, but each of the cells in the "flag" column all have the default image I set in IB--or nothing if I take that out.

According to the tutorials and StackOverflow posts I've looked through, it *seems* that I'm doing everything right--but obviously I've messed up something.

Comment: You have a lot of usages of `?.` , which is just *begging* for errors like this. `cellView.imageView?.image =` is expressing "if the `imageView` of this `cellView` is `nil`, do absolutely nothing". And well, absolutely nothing is happening, just as you requested! :) You're better off force unwrapping, because if a particular cell doesn't have an imageView, that's a bug caused by an issue in your program, which is unrecoverable at run-time.

Comment: Is the `imageView` outlet of the cell view connected to the image view?

Comment: Does `NSImage(named: flags[row])` return an image?

Comment: @Alexander: Thanks! It certainly does crash if I force unwrap, which seems to tell me that cellView doesn't have an imageView. (right?) Unfortunately, I'm still really unsure why that is.

Comment: @Willeke: Yes, `NSImage(named: flags[row])` returns an image elsewhere. As to your other question, I'm unsure--I don't think so, because the only outlet I manually connected was the `tableView`.

Comment: Here's the cell in IB: https://www.screencast.com/t/yo3IB7mn1OM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In response to the screen cast shared in the comments)

Notice how that Image View (in the cell) is not referenced by anything (its "Referencing Outlets" section on the right is empty).

Your image view is a subview of its cell (as indicated by its position in the view heiarchy on the left side bar), so you could presumably access it using something like:

```
let imageView = cell.subViews.first(where: { $0 is NSImageView }) as! NSImageView
imageView.image = NSImage(named: flags[row])
```

...but that's obviously clunky.

Instead, you should select your cell, and drag from its `imageView` outlet, to the Image View. This will make a new reference, which will make `cell.imageView` non-nil.

Alternatively, I would suggest you just delete your cell, and create a new one from the "Image & Test Table Cell View" from the "Object Library". It'll have all the outlets hooked up already.

Comment: Hooking up the outlet as you suggested worked. Thanks!
I also tried the "Image & Text Table Cell View", which also worked.

Comment: Happy to hear it. Sorry you had to go through this, I bet it was frustrating. In the future, I'd suggest using caution around `?.` It's convenient, yes, silences failures. Sometimes that's a good thing, and sometimes, like this, it's not.

Comment: but* silences failures